# jquery click element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got list of elements, when i click on first other 10 are also active,
how to target only one that is really active?
this is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.inspiration-row').on('click', function() {
        $('inspiration-block').toggleClass('shift-left shift-right');
        //$('.inspiration-block').toggleClass('span12 span8');
        $('.inspiration-right').toggleClass('span0 span2');
    });
});
```

Comment: use `$(this).toggleClass('shift-left shift-right');`

Comment: is your element dynamically added?

Comment: no, it's static list

Comment: can you share html so i can create a fiddle

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/xjomye97/

Here it is, effect dont work on fiddle, for some reason, but this is html, (one element) and i just copy paste ten times this html

Comment: [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/xjomye97/1/) if you check dev tools the class is toggling.. what do you want to happening with the class?

Comment: to toogle, everything is fine with effect, only, this, problem, with active elements..

Comment: with your js toogle dont work anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112102/discussion-between-guradio-and-mr-dont-know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [a fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/km41exqx/2/) to demonstrate my solution (let me know if it does not do exactly what you intended).

```
$(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.inspiration-row', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.inspiration-row');
    target.find('.inspiration-block').toggleClass('shift-left shift-right');
    //$('.inspiration-block').toggleClass('span12 span8');
    target.find('.inspiration-right').toggleClass('span0 span2');
  });
});
```

This registers a ready callback that captures `$` so if another script loads jquery, it won't affect us. It uses event delegation to capture all `click` events on the entire page that occur inside an element matching `.inspiration-row`.

The `event.target` refers to the source of the event, the element that the event came from. I use `.closest` to search up from the one actually clicked to find the nearest ancestor that matches `.inspiration-row`.

From there, `target` refers to that whole `.inspiration-row`, we look for those two descendent selectors and toggle the appropriate classes.

You were toggling both class names, as though that would make it pick one or the other. That is only true if the element initially has one of those names. I added one of the class names to the first `inspiration-row` so the toggles will make it have one or the other, at any one time.

Comment: I expanded the fiddle test case to demonstrate that it solves the "every one on the page" problem.

Answer (score 2):

Following this js fiddle link you can get an answer of your question according to your requirement.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jdiazs/9r2tbLn8/12/)

Let us consider set of p tags in your html page .

```
<p class="active">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
<p>Click me one!</p>
<p>Click me two!</p>
<p>Click me three!</p>
<p>Click me four!</p>
```

To handle active p tag use the following jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function(event) {
    $(event.target.tagName).not(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

And add this class in your html page in style tag.

```
.active {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace your click call back function with something like the below to target the specific block you're interested in:

```
function( event ) {
  $(event.target).closest('.inspiration-block').toggleClass('shift-left shift-right');
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).toggleClass('shift-left shift-right');
```